# Extjs 5 class not found when lunch application

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I am using Extjs 5.0.1, trying to implement basic app. This is my folder structure:

```
Project
  app
    controller
    model
    store 
    view
      MainView.js
  app.js

OtherFolder
  index.html
```

Note: `index.html` file is in other location than app.js

This is my index.html file

```
index.html 
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/5.1.0/build/ext-all.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/5.1.0/build/packages/ext-theme-crisp/build/ext-theme-crisp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Project/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="tables"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my app.js file:

```
//app.js
Ext.define('GestioneTit.app.Application',
{
        extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

        name: 'GestioneTit',

        launch: function(){

            Ext.create('GestioneTit.view.MainView');

        }
});

Ext.application('GestioneTit.app.Application');
```

This is my MainView.js file:

```
//MainView.js
Ext.define('GestioneTit.view.MainView',
{
        extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',

        tabPosition: "left",
        tabRotation: 0,
        width: 900,
        height: 1000,
        activeTab: 0,
        items: [
        {
                title: 'Tab 111111111111111111111111111111 22111221',
                html: 'A simple tab'
        }],
        renderTo: "tables"
});
```

The problem is when I lunch my application I view this error in console:

```
[W] [Ext.Loader] Synchronously loading 'GestioneTit.view.MainView'; consider adding Ext.require('GestioneTit.view.MainView') above Ext.onReady

SCRIPT5022: [Ext.create] Unrecognized class name / alias: GestioneTit.view.MainView
```

I have follow the guides in the official Sencha website, but it seems not working.

I analyzed the http request and I noticed a 404 when the loader try to load the MainView.js file. It produce a wrong url.

Comment: Why not using Sencha Cmd?

Comment: Becouse I am developing in enterprise factory and is not possible

Comment: Ok, found the problem: the ajax request return me 404. I am using a web server, but problem is I have the index.html file in other path. I just realized that the index.html is not a in the same level of app.js but is in other folder. Now I edit the original post

Comment: Why you want to have lunch your application ? Try not to eat the classes so you can find them. Or ask the waiter for a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a typical ExtJS application, you place your source code in a folder called `app` directly under the folder you put the `index.html` file in. You haven't done that – as a result, the Ajax request to load the view class goes to the wrong place (as you've seen).

What you need to do is tell ExtJS *where* your code lives. And for that, `Ext.Loader.setPath` is your friend.

For example: `Ext.Loader.setPath('GestioneTit', '../Project/app')`

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.0-classic/#!/api/Ext.Loader-method-setPath

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the view to the views config in Application.js:

```
Ext.define('GestioneTit.app.Application',
{
        extend: 'Ext.app.Application',

        name: 'GestioneTit',
        views: [
            'GestioneTit.view.MainView'
        ],
        launch: function(){

            Ext.create('GestioneTit.view.MainView');

        }
});

Ext.application('GestioneTit.app.Application');
```